# Playwright running fine on my own desktop, but 403 Forbidden in AWS Ubuntu

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, playwright

I have an ubuntu pro 22.04 on AWS and use playwrigth to perform web scraping.
I tested on my own computer and everything is OK.
I also tested on AWS ubnutu, and the results showed that there was no problem with other web pages, except this website "https://tixcraft.com/activity".
No matter what I try, such as going directly to "https://tixcraft.com/activity" or clicking to enter the tixcraft website from anywhere, as soon as I enter the tixcraft website, the message 403 Forbidden will appear.
How can I bypass this 403 Forbidden?
Is it a user-agent problem, or should I set something in the security group?

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright, Playwright
from playwright.sync_api import expect, Page

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    context_tixcraft = browser.new_context()
    page_tixcraft = context_tixcraft.new_page()

    print('tixcraft start!')
    page_tixcraft.goto("https://tixcraft.com/activity")

    page_tixcraft.wait_for_load_state('load')
    page_tixcraft.wait_for_timeout(1500)

    page_content = page_tixcraft.content()
    print(page_content)
    # 403 forbidden

    page_tixcraft.wait_for_timeout(1500)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an IP ban try with a `proxy` if you have one